# "That has to be dealt with tomorrow."

Tags: phrase-meaning

When should it be dealt with? By the end of the tomorrow, before tomorrow ends, or during tomorrow?

*He requests assistance on an urgent matter that has to be dealt with tomorrow.*

Comment: There's no difference between "by the end of tomorrow", "before tomorrow ends", and "during tomorrow".  What are you asking?

Comment: Sorry, there's a difference between 'during tomorrow' and the other two.  I typed too quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *He requests assistance on an urgent matter that has to be dealt with tomorrow.*
>
> When should it be dealt with?

Without clarification, there is is simply no way of answering the question with any precision.

> "When?"
>   "I don't know, he wasn't specific. 'Sometime,' but your guess is as good as mine."

In theory, it could be anytime at all between 12:01 a.m. and 11:59 p.m. on the next day. (Although it's doubtful that's what *he* actually meant.)

Comment: Well in this case i think this topic can be considered as concluded. Thanks.